# Swipe to delete animation overlaps with other tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have installed a swipe-to-delete function in my tableview. Nothing special there. However, when performed, the red delete button (row action) overlaps while retracting to the right with the cell below even though the deleted cell has already disappeared.

In the editActionsForRowAt function I first remove the value from the array and then from a reference in Firebase. Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Verwijder") { action, index in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let item = self.joinedArrayFiltered[editActionsForRowAt.section][editActionsForRowAt.row]
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: editActionsForRowAt.row, section: editActionsForRowAt.section)

        self.joinedArrayFiltered[editActionsForRowAt.section].remove(at: editActionsForRowAt.row)
                    self.ref.child("productsObserver").child(item.productId).child("wishlistUsers").child(self.userID).removeValue()

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = .red

    return [delete]
}
```

To help visualize the issue, please see the attached GIF below.

[image: Animated GIF >> Swipe animation shows delete area overlap with cell below]

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147342/delaying-the-model-and-table-view-change-in-commiteditingstyle

Comment: possible, but I am not doing a batch operation, not using _commitEditingStyle_ in this case. I changed the _UITableViewRowAction_ style to .default and there is a change. no overlapping but still not the desired effect.

Comment: @MatthewNiederberger did you find a solution to this?